# DNS OVER HTTPS In flutter

Tags: flutter, http, https, dns, dio

I used dio in my flutter project  .

I send a request to some domain in my project that are restrict  in my country. So  requests are failing . I decide to use dns for solved this problem .

I have DNS and DNS-over-HTTPS .

But after lot of search in google and stackoverflow , I could not find anyway to change default dns in my application or how how to use foo.domain.com/dns-query .

Is there any way to change default dns to custom dns or use dns over  https in flutter application ?

In curl i use :

`curl --doh-url https://foo.domain.com/dns-query https://www.example.com`